# Switch from single machine to multiple in Vagrant without losing the original

Tags: vagrant

I have the following vagrant VM:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8001, host: 8081

  config.vm.synced_folder "../..", "/home/edgleweb"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4000"
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./provisioner.sh", args: "edgleweb" #, run: "always"
end
```

I am having some issues with my VM which I use for development. I would like to spin another exact copy of it after a `box update`. I don't want to copy and paste the folder as that is against DRY principle. Vagrant documentation calls for a multi-machine setup as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "apache"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "mysql"
  end
end
```

But I *do* want to keep my initial VM intact until I fully test the new one. I don't want to lose it. It is not apparent from the documentation how I keep it. How do I keep it?

Comment: seems the one in single-machine setup called 'default'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `vagrant snapshot` command with either the `save` or `push` sub-commands to achieve this. See the documentation [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html).

Comment: That seems like a great feature!

Comment: Willem van Ketwich: do you know if destroying a machine would also delete its snapshots? If yes, how can I spin up a *new* one without destroying the old one?

Comment: Yes, it will destroy the snapshots too. You can make a copy of the entire folder, delete the .vagrant folder and call vagrant up on the new folder.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid, if at all possible.

Comment: You shouldn't need to destroy the vm if modifying the Vagrantfile. You should be able to run vagrant reload and it will rerun the instance and network provisioning from the vagrant file.

Comment: It shouldn't. Read the docs: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/reload.html